# How to search for specific extension of a filename matching a certain pattern

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a bunch of files organized liked so:

```
fre_3434_a2.txt
fre_3434_a2.csv
fre_3546_a2.txt...
```

I want to find the file that matches the pattern "3434" and the extension ".txt"  I've tried this but it hasn't worked:

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('.'):
for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '[3434]*.txt'):
    print(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

How can I search for a specific pattern in a file as well as a specific extension?

Comment: search for re module and use the power of Regular Expression.

Comment: I didn't think I needed regular expressions since I know the exact pattern I'm looking for?

Comment: @e9e9s you do know that`re` module takes patterns and yields what it finds based on the pattern right ? What you are trying to do is basically one of the major point of `re`.

Comment: There is another way to do it where you try and find the `3434` and `.txt` pattern as a sub string in it.... if you really don't want to use `re`

Comment: `for filename in [x for x in filenames if '3434' in x and x.endswith('.txt')]` should do just fine.

Comment: @MooingRawr thanks for clarifying that -- I'm a beginner and didn't know you could use re in that manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*3434*.txt'):
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

`"*3434*.txt"` instead of `[3434]*.txt`.